# Converting ENFA To DFA and ENFA NFA

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

here Two problem ->

problem number 1 = Question: Convert the following ENFA to DFA [using Direct Method].

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNzv.png)

problem number 2 = Question: Convert the following ENFA to NFA.

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3mlU.png)

I tried again and again, but I can't

Comment: A question should be about *one* problem. You provided images of 6 NFAs. Ask about one only. Secondly, you should show your work and what it is holding you back.

Answer (score 0):

**problem number 1:**

Steps to convert E-NFA to DFA :

1. Take E-closure for the beginning state of NFA as beginning
   state of DFA.
2. Find the states that can be traversed from the present for each input symbol (union of transition value and their closures for each states of NFA present in current state of DFA).
3. If any new state is found take it as current state and repeat step 2.
4. Do repeat Step 2 and Step 3 until no new state present in DFA transition table.
5. Mark the states of DFA which contains final state of NFA as final states of DFA.

I am converting First E-NFA to DFA

closure(1) = {1,2}

transition table for DFA is
[image]

DFA for given NFA is
[image]

Here D stands for Dead state !!

**problem number 2 :**

problem number 2 can be solved with solution of problem 1. You just not need to add dead state in NFA.